# How to remove text between <script></script> tags

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I want to remove the content between `<script></script>`tags. I'm manually checking for the pattern and `iterating` using while loop. But, I'm getting `StringOutOfBoundException` at this line:

```
String script = source.substring(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex);
```

Below is the complete method:

```java
public static String getHtmlWithoutScript(String source) {
    String START_PATTERN = "<script>";
    String END_PATTERN = " </script>";
    while (source.contains(START_PATTERN)) {
        int startIndex=source.lastIndexOf(START_PATTERN);
        int endIndex=source.indexOf(END_PATTERN,startIndex);

        String script=source.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
        source.replace(script,"");
    }
    return source;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? And I'm getting `endIndex=-1`. Can anyone help me to identify, why my code is breaking.

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = "<script>This is dummy text to remove </script> dont remove this";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    String startTag = "<script>";
    String endTag = "</script>";

    //removing the text between script
    sb.replace(text.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length(), text.indexOf(endTag), "");

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

If you want to remove the script tags too add the following line :

```
sb.toString().replace(startTag, "").replace(endTag, "")
```

**UPDATE** :

If you dont want to use `StringBuilder` you can do this:

```
    String text = "<script>This is dummy text to remove </script> dont remove this";
    String startTag = "<script>";
    String endTag = "</script>";

    //removing the text between script
    String textToRemove = text.substring(text.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length(), text.indexOf(endTag));
    text = text.replace(textToRemove, "");

    System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to remove the script tag content:

```
public String removeScriptContent(String html) {
         if(html != null) {
            String re = "<script>(.*)</script>";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                return html.replace(matcher.group(1), "");
            }
        }
        return null;
     }
```

You have to add this two imports:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: did you actually test this ?

Comment: I would make it lazy.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm probably late to the party. But I would like to give you a regex (really tested solution).

What you have to note here is that when it comes to regular expressions, their engines are greedy by default. So a search string such as `<script>(.*)</script>` will match the entire string starting from `<script>` up until the end of the line, or end of the file depending on the regexp options used. **This is due to the fact that the search engine uses greedy matching by default**.

Now in order to perform the match that you want to in an accurate manner... you could use "lazy" searching.

**Search with Lazy loading**
`<script>(.*?)<\/script>`

Now with that, you will get accurate results.

You can read more about about Regexp Lazy & Greedy in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
private static String removeScriptTags(String message) {
  String scriptRegex = "<(/)?[ ]*script[^>]*>";
  Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(scriptRegex);

  if(message != null) {
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(message);
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(message.length());
        while(matcher2.find()) {
          matcher2.appendReplacement(str, Matcher.quoteReplacement(" "));
        }
        matcher2.appendTail(str);
        message = str.toString();
  }
 return message;
}
```

Credit goes to nealvs: https://nealvs.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/removing-tags-from-a-string-in-java/