# crawler4j detects lines between the <script> </script> tag as text

Tags: web-crawler, html-parsing, crawler4j

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  
 </head>      
 <body> 
  <div style="width: 100%;"> This question already
  </div> 
  <div id="player"> hi crawler4j </div> 
  <script>
 player = new Clappr.Player({source: "http://123.30.215.65/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/d836ad614748cdab11c9df291254cf836f21144da20bf08142455a8735b328ca/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8",
   parentId: '#player',
   width: '100%', height: "100%",
      hideMediaControl: true,
      autoPlay: true
             }); 
 </script>   
 </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

In the line of code that I give as an example above, I do the following;

```
HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
String body = htmlParseData.getHtml();
```

`crawler4j` detects lines between the `<script> </script>` tag as text.
I want to delete everything that is between the `<script> </script>` tag in the body variable and then do `getText()`. 
do you help me, please ?

I want to print this out :

`This question already`

`hi crawler4j`

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlParseData` of `crawler4j` does not contain the full DOM tree of the fetched HTML page. For this reason, the plain HTML in its `String` representation is contained in the `HtmlParseData` object.

If you want to remove the content between the `<script>` tags, you can either

1. Use regular expression to remove it as described [on this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843295/how-to-remove-text-between-script-script-tags)
2. Use `JSoup` (which is already a dependency of `crawler4j` to parse the DOM tree and remove the `<script`> tags from the resulting tree.